# Cant found model with out an ID in rails 3.2.12

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

i ve this method. I m not at all able to understand the error which is

```
Couldn't find Company without an ID
```

in `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CustomersController#bulk_create`

This method is written to create customers for a company in bulk by taking their name and numbers in format `name:number`.

The method is as  follows:

```
def bulk_create
res = ""
comp_id = params[:customer][:selected_companies].delete_if{|a| a.blank?}.first
comp = Company.find(comp_id)
s = SentSmsMessage.new
s.set_defaults
s.data = tmpl("command_signup_ok", customer, comp) unless params[:customer][:email].length > 0
s.data = params[:customer][:email] if params[:customer][:email].length > 0
s.company = comp if !comp.nil?
s.save
unless comp_id.blank?
  params[:customer][:name].lines.each do |line|
    (name, phone) = line.split(/\t/) unless line.include?(":")
    (name, phone) = line.split(":") if line.include?(":")
    phone = phone.gsub("\"", "")
    phone = phone.strip if phone.strip.to_i > 0
    name = name.gsub("\"", "")
    name = name.gsub("+", "")
    phone = "47#{phone}" if params[:customer][:active].to_i == 1
    customer = Customer.first(:conditions => ["phone_number = ?", phone])
    if customer.nil?
      customer = Customer.new
      customer.name = name
      # customer.email
      # customer.login
      # customer.password
      customer.accepted_agreement = DateTime.now
      customer.phone_number = phone
      customer.active = true
      customer.accepted_agreement = DateTime.now
      customer.max_msg_week = params[:customer][:max_msg_week]
      customer.max_msg_day = params[:customer][:max_msg_day]
      customer.selected_companies = params[:customer][:selected_companies].delete_if{|a| a.blank?}
      res += "#{name} - #{phone}: Create OK<br />" if customer.save
      res += "#{name} - #{phone}: Create failed<br />" unless customer.save
    else
      params[:customer][:selected_companies].each do |cid|
        new_company = Company.find(cid) unless cid.blank?
        if !new_company.nil? 
          if !customer.companies.include?(new_company)
            customer.companies << new_company
            if customer.save
              res += "#{name} - #{phone}: Customer exists and the customer was added to the firm #{new_company.name}<br />"
            else
              res += "#{name} - #{phone}: Customer exist, but something went wrong during storage. Check if the client is in the firm.<br />" 
            end
          else
            res += "#{name} - #{phone}: Customer exists and is already on firm #{new_company.name}<br />"
          end
        end
      end
    end
    s.sms_recipients.create(:phone_number => customer.phone_number)
  end
  s.save
  s.send_as_sms
  @result = res
  respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render "bulk_create"}
  end
else
  @result = "You have not selected any firm to add these users. Press the back button and try again."
  respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render "bulk_create"}
  end
end
end
```

I want to update one situation here. That when i submit the form blank then it gives this error. Also if i filled the form with the values then its show the situation which the method is returning in case of fail.

```
 res += "#{name} - #{phone}: Create failed <br />"
```

The `tmpl` method

```
private
def tmpl(setting_name, customer, company = nil)
text = ""
 if customer.companies.count > 0
   sn = "#{setting_name}_#{@customer.companies.first.company_category.suffix}".downcase rescue setting_name
   text = Setting.value_by(sn) rescue ""
 end
textlenth = text.length rescue 0
 if textlenth < 3
   text = Setting.value_by(setting_name) rescue Setting.value_by("command_error")
 end
 return fill_template(text, customer, company)
end
```

From the model `customer.rb`

```
    def selected_companies=(cmps)
  cmps.delete("")
  # Check the old ones. Make a note if they are not in the list. If the existing ones are not in the new list, just remove them
  self.companies.each do |c|
    self.offer_subscriptions.find(:first, ["customer_id = ?", c]).destroy unless cmps.include? c.id.to_s
    cmps.delete c.id.to_s if cmps.include? c.id.to_s
    end

  # Then create the new ones
  cmps.each do |c2|
    cmp = Company.find(:first, ["id = ?", c2])
    if cmp && !c2.blank?
      offerSubs = offer_subscriptions.new
      offerSubs.company_id = c2
      offerSubs.save
    end
  end
end

    def selected_companies
       return self.companies.collect{|c| c.id}
    end
```

The association of customer is as follows:

```
has_many :offer_subscriptions
has_many :companies, :through => :offer_subscriptions
```

This code is written by the some one else. I m trying to understand this method but so far not being able to understand this code. 
Please help. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `params[:customer][:selected_companies].delete_if{|a| a.blank?}.first` debug and evaluate this. I think it's returning nil.

Comment: thanks rony.. m a bit newbie. can u plz guide me how to do that?

Comment: which IDE are you using? may I suggest you to use JetBrain RubyMine. and follow [these](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/debugging.html) instructions to debug.

Comment: By `IDE` i think u mean `text editor`? I m using `text-mate`.

Comment: but your are not able to debug your application with a text-editor.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting 'Couldn't find Company without an ID' error because your Company table doesn't contain record with id = comp_id

Change `comp = Company.find(comp_id)` to `comp = Company.find_by_id(comp_id)`.

This will return nil instead of an error.

Add `comp is not nil` condition is already handled in your code.

Comment: The `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` is being raised because no ID is being passed to the find, rather than there being no matching record.

Comment: since the method `find_by_id` is deprecated. So before posting here i tried `where` also. But not being able to succeed. For now it is giving error after the changes i made what u told me to do is `undefined local variable or method `customer' for #<CustomersController:0x007fbd9996da30>` on line this `s.data = tmpl("command_signup_ok", customer, comp) unless params[:customer][:email].length > 0`

Comment: You are getting error at this line "s.data = tmpl("command_signup_ok", customer, comp) unless params[:customer][:email].length > 0" because parameter customer passed to method tmpl is not defined.

Comment: ya method is defined but the parameter "customer" passed to the method is not defined.

Comment: That will not work at all. Define customer = "Your expected values of parameter customer which you want to pass in method tmpl e.g. customer = Customer.first" above the method called tmpl.

Answer (score 0):

Your comp_id line is returning nil.

```
comp_id = params[:customer][:selected_companies].delete_if{|a| a.blank?}.first
```

Post the params that get passed to this function and we could hopefully find out why. In the meantime you could enclose the block in a `begin - rescue` block to catch these errors:

```
begin
  <all your code>
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  return 'Unable to find a matching record'
end
```

Comment: actually i dont know how to find out the value of params.

Comment: I think ur asking this
`Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"I/hdXjPtO+n3eNTJk8pShj4VmCnhASgtzjfgjwBOQEw=", "customer"=>{"selected_companies"=>["", "1"], "name"=>"hamza:9021480192\r\nnivedita:8600438990", "active"=>"0", "email"=>"hey there.. how r u ??", "max_msg_week"=>"5", "max_msg_day"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Lagre Kunder"}`

Comment: the `selected_companies` is blank i guess.

Comment: The first value is blank, but your line deletes the blank ones, returning the non-blanks, then uses the first... shouldn't be throwing the error you received.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  comp = ""
  comp = Company.find(comp_id)  unless comp_id.nil?
```

instead of `comp = Company.find(comp_id)`

further `nil` checking present in your code.

Comment: ive pasted the `selected_companies` method from the model `customer.rb`. May be this can help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Reason being

params[:customer][:selected_companies].delete_if{|a| a.blank?} = []
so [].first = nil
therefor, params[:customer][:selected_companies].delete_if{|a| a.blank?}.first = nil
and comp_id is nil



So check the log file and check what is coming in the parameter "selected_companies"

when you will find the parameter, everything will be understood well....
```

Comment: `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"I/hdXjPtO+n3eNTJk8pShj4VmCnhASgtzjfgjwBOQEw=", "customer"=>{"selected_companies"=>["", "1"], "name"=>"hamza:9021480192\r\nnivedita:8600438990", "active"=>"0", "email"=>"hey there.. how r u ??", "max_msg_week"=>"5", "max_msg_day"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Lagre Kunder"}`

Comment: the first part of the selected companies is blank.